# Trigger task on ECS Fargate based on SQS Queue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, aws-fargate

For my application, I'm trying to use ECS Fargate to run a computing task. I want ECS Fargate to be able to service a queue of requests and autoscale as needed. In other words, the backend of my app should ideally write to a queue in SQS with the data needed to run the task and ECS Fargate should poll the SQS queue and run the tasks as needed and return the output. How would I construct an architecture like this using Python Boto 3? Can someone provide a working code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would configure the ECS auto-scaling to scale based on the SQS `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` [metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html). It could scale down to 0 ECS Fargate tasks when there are 0 messages visible, and scale up to multiple tasks polling the queue based on the scaling configuration you configure.

Inside each task your Python code would have a loop where it polls the SQS queue using the Boto3 [receive_message](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message) method. Ideally using [long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html). Inside the loop your code would take each message that was received and do whatever processing you need to do on that message, then call [delete_message](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.delete_message) when it has successfully processed the message.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really appreciate it. I was wondering if this behavior can be configured within the AWS console itself so that in the backend of my application, I can simply submit tasks to the queue and rest easy knowing ECS fargate would service tasks from the queue? If so, can you describe step by step (or link a really good resource) how I would do this?

Comment: ECS has no built-in integration with SQS. I would have mentioned that in my answer if it did. What you are talking about is available for AWS Lambda, but for ECS you have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you by any chance have an good example of ECS polling SQS queue that I can refer to?

Comment: You would just write the code that runs in your docker container to poll SQS. It would be no different from code running on EC2 or even code running on your local computer. There's nothing ECS specific about that.

Comment: After thinking about it more, I think I understand how to write the script for ECS fargate cluster to poll the SQS queue. I think it's just simply a matter of creating a poller.py script and then making sure that script executes on the docker image for the ECS Fargate instance that gets pushed to ECR